# Changing style based on height of element

Tags: jquery

I want to change the the position of an anchor tag based on the height of my h3 tag. The code below isn't working, am I doing it right?

All it says is that if my h3 tag is greater than 17px then look for the parent div (.'news')
 and style the anchor tag within the element.

```
 if ($('.news h3').height() > 17){
$(this).parent('a').css("bottom","20px");
 }
```

Comment: You might want to check what `$(this)` refers to by putting `console.log( $(this) )` inside the if statement and then checking the console. That could make it clearer. ( If that really is all of the related code. )

Comment: try it like if (parseInt($('.news h3').height()) > 17)

Comment: How is the height of the <h3> defined in the first place? If all <h3>'s are the same height, you don't need to do this. If the height changes based on class, it's easier to check with hasClass(). If it's an inline style, I would strongly suggest avoiding inline styles.

Comment: that text will eventually come from a feed and some of the text will run on to 2 lines. I will need to determine whether or not it has run on to 2 lines so I can re-position an element using css. So say the height of `<h3>` is `16px`, if it runs on to 2 lines it will change to `32px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector `$('.news h3')` returns an array of jQuery elements. If you have more than one `h3` (within `.news`) `.height()` will return height of the first one.

Let's say for each one ..

```
$('.news h3').each(function () {
  if ($(this).height() > 17) {
    $(this).parent('a').css('bottom', '20px');
  }
});
```

Note that using `.parent('a')` here, your `<h3>` must be right under `<a>`, if it is not, try `$(this).parents('a').eq(0).css('bottom', '20px');`

Comment: I have 3 `<h3>` tags in my div, one of them is greater than 17px (the 2nd one). How can I search inside `<div class="news">` and find the one I want? I've tried a few things now but nothing's worked.

Comment: `$('.news h3').eq(1).height()` should do the trick. (docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq/))

Comment: could have done, but this will be coming from a feed eventually, so I won't be able to target a specific h3 tag.

Comment: Done a jsfiddle with my code, my `a` tag is in my `news` div: http://jsfiddle.net/AJK5d/6/ - it's the middle `a` tag that needs to be re-positioned

Comment: Great. Got it working with a combo of your answer and 'Lollero - http://jsfiddle.net/TcV2e/5/ Thanks